# SQL variables; declaring when a parameter is not present

Tags: sql-server, ado.net, ssms

I'm writing a sql script, and I'd like to use Management Studio to develop the query, and a C# program to run it in production.

My query contains parameters, like so;

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE id = @id
```

I can feed in a value for `@id` in the C# program, and that works nicely. However, I also want to declare default values for testing in Management Studio. So I really want to write something like this pseudocode;

```
if not declared @id
  declare @id int
  set @id=43
end if

SELECT * FROM TABLE   
WHERE id = @id
```

Is there any way to check to see if a variable name has already been taken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to make some progress by marking out the default variables in the script, like so;

```
/** DEFAULTS **/

declare @id int
set @id = 43

/** END DEFAULTS **/
```

Then preprocessing the script in my C# program, like so;

```
script = RemoveBlock(script, "DEFAULTS");
```

And implementing the function like so;

```
public static string RemoveBlock(string script, string blockName)
{
    if (script == null) { return null; }

    var startTag = string.Format("/** {0} **/", blockName);
    var endTag = string.Format("/** END {0} **/", blockName);

    var startTagIdx = script.IndexOf(startTag);
    if (startTagIdx == -1) { return script; }

    var endTagIdx = script.IndexOf(endTag, startTagIdx + startTag.Length);
    if (endTagIdx == -1) { return script; }

    var endOfEndTag = endTagIdx + endTag.Length;

    var beforeBlock = script.Substring(0, startTagIdx);
    var afterBlock = script.Substring(endOfEndTag);

    return beforeBlock + afterBlock;
}
```

So the C# program runs a version without the variables but with parameters.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do exactly what you're after. I'd suggest either:

1) wrap the script up as a sproc and give defaults for the params
2) include a comment block at the top of the script that you can then uncomment when running in SSMS:

```
/*
-- Default variables for testing
DECLARE @Id INTEGER
SET @Id = 43
*/
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE id = @Id
```

Comment: Hi. I'd had similar thoughts... I can't modify the database, so I can't write it as an SP; The comment block is the way I'm going at the moment.

Comment: One suggestion: use the -- instead of /*, so you can use comment and uncomment toolbar buttons in management studio.